# For Prestashop: use 2 query for value with IF ELSE.. how declare new variable?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, prestashop, declare

I have table `ps_orders` with (total_paid) and (current_state)

If current state is "3" write `$total_paid`
if isn't "3" write "0"

I extracted `$total_paid` value, but i cannot declare `$current_state` variable

```
$query_cod = "SELECT total_paid FROM ps_orders WHERE current_state = 3":

$result_cod = mysql_query($query_cod);

    while ($row_cod = mysql_fetch_array($result_cod))
    $total_paid = $row_cod['total_paid'];
```

---

```
    if ($current_state == 3) {
    fwrite($file, "total_paid"); //38
    } 

    elseif ($current_state == 2) {
    fwrite($file, "|"); //38
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query_cod = "SELECT total_paid, current_state FROM ps_orders";
$result_cod = mysql_query($query_cod);

while ($row_cod = mysql_fetch_array($result_cod)) {
    $total_paid = $row_cod['total_paid'];
    $current_state = $row_cod['current_state'];
    if ($current_state == 3) {
        fwrite($file, "total_paid"); //38
    } 

    elseif ($current_state == 2) {
        fwrite($file, "|"); //38
    } 
}
```

EDIT : As @Ivan Hanák said, your comparaison is useless as long as you have the `where` statement in your SQL query.
I have corrected my code, I guess it's what you want to do...

And also, do not use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated. Get a look at [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your loop.

Look, you are grabbing rows from a database based on a condition `WHERE current_state = 3"`. So, the following `if/else` statement is useless, since the variable `$row_cod` contains only records regarding `current_state = 3` and in a single row there is not such a key `current_state`, for you do not request in the sql query.

You should remove the `WHERE` clause and then do the comparing.

(Or just provide more info, what you want to accomplish.)

**EDIT:**

```
if ($row_cod['current_state'] == 3)
    fwrite($file, "total_paid");
elseif ($row_cod['current_state'] == 2)
    fwrite($file, "|");
```

*Do not forget to add `current_state` into you sql query*

Comment: thanks, but in all orders will write "total_paid"..
I understeand my mystake
i removed WHERE current_state = 3 but does not work...

Comment: You did not finish the task :). Since ou have removed `WHERE`, now, you are to use your conditional statement, I provided code sample into my edit. However do not expect me to help you more with your issue, unless you provide more detailed info, what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, here code, but I have a little question

$query_cod = "SELECT total_paid, current_state FROM ps_orders WHERE id_order = " . $id_order;
        $result_cod = mysql_query($query_cod);

```
    while ($row_cod = mysql_fetch_array($result_cod)) 

        {
            $total_paid = $row_cod['total_paid'];
            $current_state = $row_cod['current_state'];

            if ($current_state == 3)
            {
                fwrite($file, "$total_paid" . "|"); //40
                fwrite($file, "EUR|"); //41
                fwrite($file, "CON|"); //42 
            } 

            elseif ($current_state == 2)
            {
                fwrite($file, "|"); //40
                fwrite($file, "|"); //41
                fwrite($file, "|"); //42
            }
```

If I insert 'total_paid' show me "total paid" 
If I insert $total_paid show me correct price
But it should be works with "total paid"...? Right?